# Connect to a webservice hosted on a server connected to VPN from the internet

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, c#

I'm currently working on a project (developed with C#) where it's necessary to access a website via VPN to access this website's data services. We host this application on a server which connect's via VPN to the customers network and a tool makes sure that this VPN connection is also established in the background.

So this application accesses the data service website via VPN, processes this data and itself hosts a webservice on a designated port range for quick access to this data.

Then we have a frontend page, also developed by us, but hosted on another server in the internet, because this frontend page needs to be accessed in public. This frontend page now has to access the webservice hosted by our application.

So now the problem is we can not do so, because if the server, where the webservice application is hosted, is connected to VPN, it's not accessible from outside the company's work.

So if we want to access this webservice, do we have any chance to do so with router settings? An idea of my boss was to access the VPN server's IP, enable the port range there and access the webservice through the VPN server IP then.. I'm not so professional with networking staff, but in my opinion the only chance would be then to use port forwarding to the webservice server then. Would that be possible? The networking team in that company say port forwarding is not neccessary, but that's hard to believe for me, because I can't imagine how, through the VPN server, the network packets can find my webservice. Is it even possible to access this webservice from outside the VPN?

Comment: a downvote for a question about something needed in production? how come? did I write too long? xD

Comment: Some people downvote anything that smells like programming (that belongs on Stack Overflow ) and to be honest this is more about application architechure than it is personal computer stuff which this site is for.  One generic tip, is that DNS resolution is often hard when using a VPN, so make sure all your names are fully qualified, the VPN connection is configured to use a DNS server that has the remote host you want to connect to on the remote end of the tunnel, and check to make sure your IP routeing is configured correctly to send the desired traffic into the tunnel.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip.
Lol, I wrote on stackoverflow before - they write my question fits better to superuser.com, now here I hear it's more a programming question.. I guess it's just something in between :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some form of port-forwarding as described *would* work, although it feels rather hacky.

I suggest focusing on "if the server is connected to VPN, it's not accessible from outside the company's work". That's something for your customer's (or maybe your own) networking team to fix. Don't let them tell you that's how VPNs work, because they don't have to work that way: it's perfectly possible to route only the company-owned prefixes through the VPN and the rest directly.

Maybe part of the issue is that the VPN server is applying the same policies to your connection from the webserver as it does with connections from employees' PCs. I'd say they should have separate and different rules, for *various* reasons. (For example, imagine that the VPN admins decide to require smartcard auth...your server connection breaks. If they decide to require that PCs have a specific Windows version or a specific antivirus system...your server connection breaks.)

Comment: I forwarded this answer to my boss. He decided to move our application to a desktop pc inside the company and use port forwarding then.
Thanks for your helpful answer!